# Regex pattern to search multiple word occurrences and capture the second matched only

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to capture the second occurrence using REGEX pattern in notepad++ which is "Florida; West Virginia; DC only."

```
 Notepad++
 1 Arkansas; Hawaii; South Dakota; North Carolina
 2 California;Florida; Washington State; New York; Florida; West Virginia; DC
 3 Nevada; Texas; New Mexico; Georgia   


Regex Pattern: '\Florida(.*?)\DC'

Actual Capture: Florida; Washington State; New York; Florida; West Virginia; DC
Desired Capture: Florida; West Virginia; DC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead asserting no more occurrences of Florida to the right.

For a match only, you don't need the capture group. Also the `\F` and `\D` do not have to be escaped.

```
\bFlorida\b(?!.*\bFlorida\b).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BXIH1K/1)

Or optionally match the first occurrence, and capture from the second occurrence on in a capture group.

```
^(?:.*?\bFlorida\b)?.*?\b(Florida\b.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3pqyIp/1)

Comment: it works with https://regex101.com and notepad++ but it does not work with REGEXP_SUBSTR SQL, the actual value in my data is on the 30th from the delimiter (;), I found approach like this "^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;([^;]*)" is there a way to shorten the pattern? This captures until the 30th (;) but it's a long pattern.

Comment: Try it like this and get the value from capture group 2 `^([^;]*;){29}([^;]*)`

Comment: Hi  @The fourth bird, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does `(?:.*)(Florida.*)` work for you?

It "matches" some things but only "captures" the last Florida and afterwards.

I tested this at https://regex101.com/r/cWqhkC/1.

Comment: Hi @AaronJ thank you for that, the idea is there but if Florida is single occurrence it does not match...it could be also capture the first occurrence from the right...

Comment: I'm using this regex https://www.regexpal.com/1926, 'Florida.*(Florida.*)' this pattern matches the first word not the second word only...

Comment: That requirement was unclear in the question. Does `https://regex101.com/r/cWqhkC/1` work for you?